# Name/Word Replacement Plugin

Tags: customization

How would I go about making a plugin that allows me to write entries with real names, but display them with designated "fake" names to protect the identity of both the writer and the people being written about without the writer doing manual mapping and replacement. I also don't want it to display without the plugin working. Like if the plugin no longer works then display "entry temporarily unavailable" or similar.

Example:

> I went to the store with James today.

Would display as something like

> I went to the store with Thomas today.

And it would hold James = Thomas in the database and never use Thomas for any other name.

Comment: Why not just have the author's pseudonym be their account name? And why not just have them write their articles with a designated pseudonym?

Comment: @belinus The whole point was to reduce the writer's work by having WordPress do the pseudonym mapping. That way they don't have to keep track of who they call who. They simply write.

Comment: Either way though, your question is off-topic for this site. It is for actual coding so if you were writing this plugin yourself and needed help with your code, it would be appropriate. Asking for plugin recommendations is not.

Comment: Oh. I searched WordPress on the StackExchange site list and saw this with the description "WordPress developers *and administrators*" so I assumed this would be fine, but I guess not. My apologies. I'll take my question down shortly.

Comment: No problem. But they do tend to get closed. A plug-in of this nature would be easy to write to do the switching. Breaking the post if it fails is a different story. All you would need to do is filter `the_content()` through a PHP string replace function and output. I would still recommend they do it themselves though. A simple Find/Replace in whatever they use to write the post will be much simpler. Their account can be their pseudonym so Bob Smith's account says his name is John Doe.

Comment: @belinus Yeah and not many writers would mention themselves in the 3rd person anyway. I'll try to turn this into a coding question, but I don't have access to a PC at the moment as I just had to RMA my motherboard.

Comment: Actually, I think I'll just take it down because once I learn the wp APIs I shouldn't need any help on it. I honestly just didn't want to reinvent the wheel if it had already been made.

Comment: I've had to do three different similar scenarios of swapping names inside post content. I posted what I would start with for you. It's a quick one to modify to get what you need. I use a meta field b/c it isn't included in wp-json by default. Not sure about user nicknames, etc. Anyway hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: @hwl It is much appreciated. I will make the plugin as soon as I get my PC back up and running. Add the mods I spoke of in the comment on your answer.

Comment: *and add the mods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a plugin or two out there that will do this (or that could be altered to), but it is solvable in two steps with three pretty simple php functions.

The quick approach may be to **1)** add a user meta box for an *author-alias* applied to authors. Then **2)** hook the `the_content` filter and `preg_replace` the author's name for the alias from within the post content.

This can be added to the *functions.php* file of your template.

(Note: *We have to hook two places for these, depending on if the user is accessing the page or an administrator*).

### Step One: Author-Alias Meta Box and Save Function

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'adding_author_content_alias' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'adding_author_content_alias' );

function adding_author_content_alias( $user ) { 

    if( user_can( $user, 'edit_posts' ) ) { //hiding this box from users below author level
        ?>

        <h3>Author Alias</h3>

        <table class="form-table">

            <tr>
                <th><label for="author-alias">Author Alias</label></th>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="author-alias" id="author-alias" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'author-alias', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                    <span class="description">Add your Author Alias.</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <?php 
    }//end if user_can
}//end adding_author_content_alias()

add_action( 'personal_options_update',  'save_author_content_alias' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_author_content_alias' );

function save_author_content_alias( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['author-alias'] ) ) {
        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'author-alias', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['author-alias'] ) );
    }
}//end save_author_content_alias()
```

**quick note:** in the `adding_author_content_alias` method above, we're using `[user_can][1]` **not** `current_user_can` so we can pass the user object of the profile being viewed, rather than the object or id of the viewer, and check caps.

### Step Two: Filtering the_content with author name and alias.

With the above new user meta in place, we can filter `the_content` rather easily:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'our_content_filter_function' );

function our_content_filter_function($content) {
    if( in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {

        $author = get_the_author();
        $author-alias = get_the_author_meta( 'author-alias' );

        $name_parts = explode(' ', $author); 
        $first_name = name_parts[0];
        $first_name = trim($first_name);

        $content = preg_replace( $first_name, $author-alias, $content );
        return $content;

    }//end if

    return $content;

}//end our_content_filter_function()
```

The three functions and five hooks above - or some version of them - should do the trick if the methodology of that approach works for what you need.

### The End ;)

### - Everything below here is just further explanation for those looking for a starting point ;)

I will layout some more details for anybody else looking for a starting point for something similar:

1) The above assumes your Authors have "*Display Name*" set to *First* and *Last Name*, in that order. If Author's Display Name is set to only First Name, just cut `$name_parts/expode/$first_name` stuff out. set `$first_name = $author;` or swap those variables in the `preg_replace()`.

2) You could do all of the above name_parts/explode with php's `[list][1]` if your php version isn't going to change.

3) If you prefer to have the aliases assigned to authors further outside of their control, you could meta key/value them as options in the db perhaps. Then match the author key by the author name and set key and value to the variables for `preg_replace()`'s `pattern` and `replacement`, respectively.

4) On the off chance you wish to replace all occurrences across the site of an author's name (or to swap character's names in serialized text, etc etc blah blah) you can pass arrays for both `pattern` and `replacement`. More on that below.

### Notes: Wordpress

We hook the [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/), since it is applied just before displaying the post, and exposes the post's content as a string set to `$content`.
We aren't changing any data in the db, but rather altering that data after the query and before it is displayed. It's late enough that any theme or plugin should be able to jump in here, so the below could go in your theme's *functions.php* without issue.

`add_filter( 'the_content', 'our_content_filter_function' );`

One thing to keep in mind with this filter is you may wish to check whether or not it is dealing with a main query. We used the recommended `[is_main_query()][2]` and `[in_the_loop()][2]` conditionals above for that reason, but if you need to alter things in secondary queries you may wish to exclude them.

```
 function our_content_filter_function($content) {
      if ( in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
         //do stuff to $content here
           return $content;
     }
    return $content;
}
```

### Notes: PHP

As mentioned above, php's `preg_replace()` can accepted arrays for both the pattern and replacement, **and** it will match them if *they are keyed and sorted*. So `$pattern[2]` will be replaced by `$replacement[2]`. But you must `[ksort()][2]` these arrays, otherwise it will match them in the order they were enter in the code; see [example 2 on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more on that.

For your needs, swapping out *James* and replacing it with *Thomas*, (I'll add a few more for the array):

```
 $pattern = array();
 $pattern[0] = 'James';
 $pattern[1] = 'Larry';
 $pattern[2] = 'Moe';
 $pattern[3] = 'Curly';

 $replacement = array();
 $replacement[1] = 'Groucho';
 $replacement[0] = 'Thomas';
 $replacement[3] = 'Chico';
 $replacement[2] = 'Harpo';

//makes sure our 1s match our 1s, and 2s match our 2s
ksort($pattern);
ksort($replacement);

//add in our $content string

preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

And now all together as a filter and callback:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'our_content_filter_function' );

function our_content_filter_function($content) {
    if( in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
         $pattern = array();
         $pattern[0] = 'James';
         $pattern[1] = 'Larry';
         $pattern[2] = 'Moe';
         $pattern[3] = 'Curly';

         $replacement = array();
         $replacement[1] = 'Groucho';
         $replacement[0] = 'Thomas';
         $replacement[3] = 'Chico';
         $replacement[2] = 'Harpo';

         //makes sure our 1s match our 1s, and 2s match our 2s
         ksort($pattern);
         ksort($replacement);

        //add in our $content string

       preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
       return $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: That is almost perfect. The only thing left to do would be convert the array replacement to a db system. Using an array setting for names to be replaced and a name pool that is automatically distributed across the names to be replaced.

Comment: You could easily grab author's name from post and grab an array of "replacement names" stored as array( 'authorname' => 'replacementname') as one db entry. Use the wp_options table to store that I think. Or just store replacement names and write something to randomize which is chosen to swap out the author's name in content. If you want it to vary, that is.

Comment: I was referring to like if the author's name is Joe, and he writes about Bob and Jill, I want to make it so it automatically rewrites/replaces Joe, Bob, and Jill with names from a pool in a assigned manner. So when Joe adds Bob to the list of names to be replaced it grabs a random name from the pool and turns it into that random name and the same for Jill and himself and it will essentially remove that randomly picked name from the pool of names.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah if Joe assigns names to be removed, you can save his assignments as post_meta with a custom box meta box. Then hook the save post action to do the assignment as another post_meta value. That way it will always be the same replacement names upon viewing the post. Really though, you may want the author or an editor to assign them in case gender matters so you don't map John to Lisa. Or use gender neutral names in the replacement list.

Comment: I figured I'd make 3 pools (masculine, feminine, and neutral) and when adding names to the list, the author could select the pool to draw from, with neutral as default.